# Why ReportViewer do not return data when created inside another ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: c#, web-applications, .net-3.5, port, reportviewer

I'm using report viewer to generate some reports.

I've created a new web application project inside my solution (that already has one web application project) and I've made it work. (Created the dataSet, webForm with the reportviewer and all the .rdlc reports)

It was working, but when I ran my solution, two ports are opened. One for my previous Web Application and another port for the new one.

Now I need to use only ONE port. The I tried to create all the same stuff that I've created this time inside the already existing WebApplication project. After this, when I ran the project, the report page open at the browser, but the data that should be returned isn't. Only the ReportViewer toolbox appears, with no data...

What would be the problem? Is it possible to use only one port to both web application projects? How? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just dicovered how to make it work. My first web applicattion was using framework 3.5 and the new one was using the framework 4.0.

I turned my new web application project to 4.0 framework, compiled and turned back to framework 3.5. Now that's all ok, working and returning data.

Probably because of the ReportViewer version. (I'm using VS 2010)

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties window for your project (rt click the .proj file and choose Properties), there should be a Web option on the left side of the screen. In the bottom half of that page there's a setting to toggle usage of the VS dev server, as well as a specific port number.

Comment: already tried this, but if both projects are set to the same port, one of them get a random free port to use